# addActionListener not working

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I followed a tutorial on how to do this - Here's the code I used:

```
package soundboard;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Soundboard {

    JButton Button1;

    public void windowCreate() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        mainsPanel = new JPanel();

        Button1 = new JButton("1");
        Button1.addActionListener(this);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.add(Button1);
        frame.add(mainsPanel);

        frame.setSize(183,245);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
    Soundboard window = new Soundboard();
    window.windowCreate();
    }
}
```

The code seems to not be working. Could anyone explain why?

The `JPanel` is used as a background. The problem is in `Button1.addActionListener(this);` , as it says that "this" is not convertible to `ActionListener` or something like so.

Comment: And that's why we must set the `@Override` annotation :)

Comment: 1) You can't use Duck typing, because of you must to implement `ActionListener` interface. 2) Seems you need to read [that](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/)

Comment: What the heck is "duck typing"?

Comment: A single blank line of white space in source code is all that is *ever* needed.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant.

Comment: I actually use those blank lines to help me think and separate the code into organized pieces. I do it constantly. Does that actually affect the code in any way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to add your class as an Onclicklistener:

```
Button1.addActionListener(this);
```

then your class must implement the appropriate interface `ActionListener` like this:

```
public class Soundboard implements ActionListener{
    //...

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    //...
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

If you have multiple buttons, that need separated implementation, you could f.e. use anonymous classes:

```
mybutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
         //does something, that probably interests only mybutton
         //declare mybutton as **final** if you must use it
    }
});
```

Comment: @Override is not recognized for some reason - explain further?

Comment: @Override was added in Java 6 / jdk 1.6. Whats your java version? Its an annotation that marks, that there is an inherited method, that gets a new(say: overwritten) implementation, while respecting the "methods contract".

Comment: Well I'm using NetBeans 8.0 and I constantly update to the latest version of java possible. Also I did try the ActionListener implementation, but it didn't work either.

Comment: Iam not using Netbeans, but Eclipse. Is their a project related property menu, where you can setup the compiler level, java runtime environment and complaint level? If so, you should check their settings, if they use your latest installed java version.

Also, show us your implementation of the actionPerformed method, please.

Comment: WAIT - I think I just got it working. There was something in the code I thought I might be able to name however I want, but that was actually not true. Although, how can I make different actionPerformed methods for different buttons?

Answer (score 4):

You need to implement the `ActionListener` interface if you want to override the `actionPerformed` method:

```
public class Soundboard implements ActionListener {
```

Answer (score 3):

You can only add `ActionListener`s to a `Component` with `addActionListener()`.

Your class has to implement `ActionListener` e.g.

```
public class Soundboard implements ActionListener {
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. Here's how I implemented it, the other buttons don't do a thing quite yet.
All the code is in a class called Soundboard, which implements ActionListener, while javax.swing* and
java.awt.event* are also imported.

```
JButton loadButton;
JButton clearButton;
JButton Button1;
JButton Button2;
JButton Button3;
JButton Button4;
JPanel mainsPanel;
int times;

public void windowCreate() {


    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    mainsPanel = new JPanel();


    loadButton = new JButton("Load...");
    loadButton.setSize(80, 30);
    loadButton.setLocation(4, 4);

    clearButton = new JButton("Clear");
    clearButton.setSize(80, 30);
    clearButton.setLocation(92, 4);


    Button1 = new JButton("1");
    Button1.setSize(80, 80);
    Button1.setLocation(4, 45);
    Button2 = new JButton("2");
    Button2.setSize(80, 80);
    Button2.setLocation(92, 45);
    Button3 = new JButton("3");
    Button3.setSize(80, 80);
    Button3.setLocation(4, 133);
    Button4 = new JButton("4");
    Button4.setSize(80, 80);
    Button4.setLocation(92, 133);

    loadButton.addActionListener(this);

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(false);

    frame.add(loadButton);
    frame.add(clearButton);
    frame.add(Button1);
    frame.add(Button2);
    frame.add(Button3);
    frame.add(Button4);
    frame.add(mainsPanel);

    frame.setSize(183,245);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);                
}
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
    times += 1;
    System.out.println("Test successful - this was the #"
                        + times + " press");
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    Soundboard window = new Soundboard();
    window.windowCreate();
}
```